# Cyclic group, automorphism, and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

The problem is taken from Dummit and Foote. I would very much appreciate any feedback! Thank you in advance.

Let $C_n$ be the cyclic group of order $n$ and for each integer $a$
        define
            $$\sigma_a:C_n\rightarrow C_n \quad \text{by}\quad 
   \sigma_a(x)=x^a\text{ for all }x \in C_n$$
(a) Prove that $\sigma_a$ is an automorphism of
                $C_n$ if and only if $a$ and $n$ are relatively
                prime.

We first prove that if $G$ is a group of order $n$ and
    $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then the map $x \mapsto x^a$ is surjective.
                We show the map is surjective by showing $|x^a|=n$. 
                Since $G$ is finite, for some integer $k$, $(x^a)^k=1$.
                Then, 
                \begin{align*}
     x^{ak} &= 1 \\
     n|ak \\
     n|k \\
     k=n 
    \end{align*}
                Hence, the map is surjective.

Suppose $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime. 
                We show $\sigma_a$ is automorphism by showing it is homomorphism and bijective.                                   We show that the map is homomorphism. For $c_1, c_2 \in C_n$,
                \begin{align*}
     \sigma_a(c_1c_2) &=(c_1c_2)^a  \\
      &= (x^kx^l)^a \\
      &= x^{ka+la} \\ 
      &= (x^k)^a(x^l)^a \\ 
      &= \sigma_a(c_1)\sigma_a(c_2)
    \end{align*}
                Hence, $\sigma_a$ is homomorphism. Since $C_n$ is finite and $\sigma_a$ is surjective 
                (by the above argument), the map is bijective. Thus, the map is automorphism.

On the other hand, suppose $\sigma_a$ is automorphism. Take $x \in C_n$ such that
                $C_n = \langle x \rangle$. 
                Then, $|\sigma_a(x)| = |x|$ since in particular $\sigma_a$ is homomorphism and injective.
                Then, $C_n = \langle x^a \rangle$. By Proposition (p. 57), we have $(a,n)=1$.

(b) Prove that $\sigma_a=\sigma_b$ if and only
                if $a\equiv b \mod n$.

Suppose $a \equiv b \mod n$. We want to show $\sigma_a = \sigma_b$.
                Since $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$ are homomorphisms and $C_n = \langle x \rangle$, 
                it suffices to show 
                \begin{align*}
     \sigma_a(x) = \sigma_b(x).
    \end{align*}
                Since $a \equiv b \mod n$, $n | (a-b)$. Therefore, 
                \begin{align*}
     x^{a-b}&=1 \\
     x^a &= x^b 
    \end{align*}
                On the other hand, suppose $\sigma_a = \sigma_b$. 
                Then, 
                \begin{align*}
     \sigma_a(x) &= \sigma_b(x) \\
     x^a &= x^b \\
     x^{a-b} &= 1 \\
     n&|(a-b) \\
     a-b &\equiv 0 \mod n \\
     a &\equiv b \mod n
    \end{align*}
                Therefore, $\sigma_a=\sigma_b$ if and only
                if $a\equiv b \mod n$.

(c) Prove that \emph{every} automorphism of $C_n$
                is equal to $\sigma_a$ for some integer $a$.

Suppose $\phi: C_n \mapsto C_n$ is an automorphism. 
                Since the range $C_n$ is cyclic, every element in $C_n$ is of the form $x^a$.
                Suppose $\phi(x)=x^a=\sigma_a(x)$ for some integer a.
                Then, this definition completely defines $\phi$ on $C_n$ as for every $x^i \in C_n$,
                \begin{align*}
    \phi(x^i) &= \phi(x)^i \\
     &= (x^a)^i \\
     &= (x^{i})^a \\
     &= \sigma_a(x^i)
    \end{align*}
                Hence, \emph{every} automorphism of $C_n$
                is equal to $\sigma_a$ for some integer $a$.

(d)Prove that $\sigma_a \circ \sigma_b=\sigma_{ab}$.
                Deduce that the map $\overline{a}\mapsto \sigma_a$ is
                an isomorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ onto the
                automorphism group of $C_n$ (so $\text{Aut}(C_n)$ is
                an abelian group of order $\phi(n)$).

We first show that the composition of two homomorphisms are homomorphism.
                Since $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$ are homomorphism, for $g_1, g_2 \in C_n$,
                \begin{align*}
     \sigma_a \circ \sigma_b (g_1g_2) &= \sigma_a(\sigma_b(g_1)\sigma_b(g_2)) \\
      &= \sigma_a(\sigma_b(g_1))\sigma_a(\sigma_b(g_2)) \\
      &=  (\sigma_a \circ \sigma_b)(g_1)(\sigma_a \circ \sigma_b)(g_2).
    \end{align*}
                Thus, the composition of two homomorphisms are homomorphism.
                Note,
                \begin{align*}
     \sigma_a \circ \sigma_b (x) &= (x^b)^a \\
      &= x^{ab} \\
      &= \sigma_{ab}(x)
    \end{align*}
                Since $\sigma_a \circ \sigma_b$ and  $\sigma_{ab}$ are homomorphisms such that
                $\sigma_a \circ \sigma_b(x) = \sigma_{ab}(x)$ where $C_n= \langle x \rangle$, 
                $\sigma_a \circ \sigma_b$ = $\sigma_{ab}$.
                Define $\Phi: \left( \mathbb{Z}/n \right)^{\times} \rightarrow Aut(C_n)$ by 
                $\Phi(\overline{a}) = \sigma_a$. By the above argument, $\Phi$ is homomorphism.
                That is, $\Phi(\overline{a}\overline{b}) = \Phi(\overline{a})\Phi(\overline{b})$. 
                By part $(b)$, $\Phi$ is well-defined.
                By part $(c)$, $\Phi$ is surjective.
                Since $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ is finite, $\Phi$ is bijective and thus is isomorphism.